# how to run linux commands after logging into to a gateway controlled device

Tags: bash

I am brand new to linux/bash scripting and I am trying to write a script to run commands on a device connected to a gateway machine. The script is being run on the gateway machine and the device connected requires authentication.
1) ssh root@xyz
2) cd /mnt/abc/xyz
3) Play command

1) runs and asks for password and logs into the device, but it stops here and does not run 2) and 3). How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting up passwordless login.  http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

After that, put your commands into a file commands.sh in root's home directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/abc/xyz
Play command
```

Then make that file executable by running this command in bash:

```
chmod 750 commands.sh
```

finally, you can run this all remotely with the command

```
ssh root@xyz ./commands.sh
```